# Thinkpad T480 on Ubuntu 18.04LTS - Touchpad stopped working as of February 9, 2019

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad

The Touchpad worked fine previously on my Thinkpad. Never had issues.

For some reason it has stopped working.

Not sure what the issue is, **journalctl** shows no issues, I've tried rebooting and installing the older driver via: `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

Then I rebooted.

Sadly it did not fix anything.

```
$ journalctl -kf
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-01-31 23:27:56 CST. --
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU4: Core temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU5: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU3: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU1: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 10:45:34 reinhard-T480 kernel: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
Feb 10 11:24:15 reinhard-T480 kernel: perf: interrupt took too long (3954 > 3938), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50500

$ sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Version && sudo dmidecode -t system | grep SKU

Version: ThinkPad T480
SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_20L6_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T480

$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Raydium Corporation Raydium Touch System  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated IR Camera: Integrate           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

$

[image: Terminal screenshot]

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: Hardware issue?

Comment: Can you tell us your more precise laptop model. You can find it like this: `sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Version && sudo dmidecode -t system | grep SKU`. For me `journalctl -kf` showed me some problems with my touchpad.

Comment: I did it, and added to top and here it is as well: Version: ThinkPad T480
SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_20L6_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPad T480, added journalctl -kf